# JSON Parsing with jq process

Tags: json, parsing

I have a JSON that I need to modify one of the key values because the date field has extra content.
I think I'm struggling with drilling down with the repaired xml to make the JSON. It works as is but just want to remove the first word in the results aka the full day (Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday) in "ConnectedTime", "LastHeardTime" throughout the Json.

```
{
  "root": {
    "Version": "2.5.3",
    "XLX207linkedpeers": null,
    "XLX207linkednodes": {
      "NODE": [
        {
          "Callsign": "K9TON   B",
          "IP": "9.9.9.9",
          "LinkedModule": "A",
          "Protocol": "YSF",
          "ConnectTime": "Sunday Sun Dec 10 13:52:03 2023",
          "LastHeardTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 18:29:29 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "AG7AZ   B",
          "IP": "9.9.9.9",
          "LinkedModule": "C",
          "Protocol": "DCS",
          "ConnectTime": "Sunday Sun Dec 10 13:52:44 2023",
          "LastHeardTime": "Sunday Sun Dec 10 17:05:13 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "AG7AZ   B",
          "IP": "9.9.9.9",
          "LinkedModule": "A",
          "Protocol": "YSF",
          "ConnectTime": "Monday Mon Dec 11 23:39:48 2023",
          "LastHeardTime": "Monday Mon Dec 11 23:39:48 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "K9TON   D",
          "IP": "9.9.9.9",
          "LinkedModule": "C",
          "Protocol": "DCS",
          "ConnectTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 03:29:05 2023",
          "LastHeardTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 03:29:05 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "K9TON   B",
          "IP": "9.9.9.9",
          "LinkedModule": "A",
          "Protocol": "YSF",
          "ConnectTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 04:45:41 2023",
          "LastHeardTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 14:38:02 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "KK7OVZ  B",
          "IP": "9.9.9.9",
          "LinkedModule": "A",
          "Protocol": "YSF",
          "ConnectTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 08:38:25 2023",
          "LastHeardTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 18:29:14 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "NC1D    B",
          "IP": "9.9.9.9",
          "LinkedModule": "C",
          "Protocol": "DCS",
          "ConnectTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 10:00:27 2023",
          "LastHeardTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 14:00:09 2023"
        }
      ]
    },
    "XLX207heardusers": {
      "STATION": [
        {
          "Callsign": "KQ4DZY",
          "Vianode": "K9TON   B",
          "Onmodule": "A",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 18:29:29 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "W6PNK",
          "Vianode": "KK7OVZ  B",
          "Onmodule": "A",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 18:29:14 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "K9TON",
          "Vianode": "K9TON   B",
          "Onmodule": "A",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 18:17:54 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "AG7AZ",
          "Vianode": "K9TON   B",
          "Onmodule": "A",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 18:16:53 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "N9MAS",
          "Vianode": "N9MAS   B",
          "Onmodule": "A",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 18:04:29 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "KO4ZUL",
          "Vianode": "K9TON   B",
          "Onmodule": "A",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 17:16:19 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "NC1D",
          "Vianode": "K9TON   B",
          "Onmodule": "A",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 16:17:10 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "NC1D     / JOEL",
          "Vianode": "NC1D    B",
          "Onmodule": "C",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 14:00:09 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "NC1D",
          "Vianode": "NC1D    B",
          "Onmodule": "A",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 13:55:19 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "BG5VIG   / ID52",
          "Vianode": "BG5VIG  B",
          "Onmodule": "B",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 09:12:38 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "KB9MQD",
          "Vianode": "K9TON   B",
          "Onmodule": "A",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 08:07:47 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "KG4ISH",
          "Vianode": "K9TON   B",
          "Onmodule": "A",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Tuesday Tue Dec 12 01:12:07 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "AG5NO",
          "Vianode": "K9TON   B",
          "Onmodule": "A",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Monday Mon Dec 11 22:26:21 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "K7TTM",
          "Vianode": "K9TON   B",
          "Onmodule": "A",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Monday Mon Dec 11 21:35:16 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "KK7OVZ",
          "Vianode": "KK7OVZ  B",
          "Onmodule": "A",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Monday Mon Dec 11 18:32:44 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "AG7AZ",
          "Vianode": "AG7AZ   B",
          "Onmodule": "A",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Monday Mon Dec 11 18:32:34 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "KC6LDN",
          "Vianode": "K9TON   B",
          "Onmodule": "A",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Sunday Sun Dec 10 23:59:52 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "KA5JKI",
          "Vianode": "K9TON   B",
          "Onmodule": "A",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Sunday Sun Dec 10 18:24:51 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "KK7NLO",
          "Vianode": "K9TON   B",
          "Onmodule": "A",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Sunday Sun Dec 10 18:13:13 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "KA5JKI",
          "Vianode": "KA5JKI  B",
          "Onmodule": "A",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Sunday Sun Dec 10 18:10:07 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "AG7AZ    / ID52",
          "Vianode": "AG7AZ   B",
          "Onmodule": "C",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Sunday Sun Dec 10 17:05:16 2023"
        },
        {
          "Callsign": "K7DCE",
          "Vianode": "K9TON   B",
          "Onmodule": "A",
          "Viapeer": "XLX207",
          "LastHeardTime": "Sunday Sun Dec 10 15:47:47 2023"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried running through the jq help files and the GitHub but can't come up with a path that can delete just the first word in a key value.
`$.root.XLX207heardusers.STATION.LastHeardTime`
`$.root.XLX207linkednodes.NODE.ConnectedTime`
`$.root.XLX207linkednodes.NODE.LastHeardTime`

Comment: `STATION` and `NODE` are arrays. You need to access their entries via index